# WordPress's wp_get_attachment_image_srcset is not returning all the image srcset sizes

Tags: wordpress, responsive, srcset

I have a small function in my WordPress theme that returns responsive images - or at least, it is supposed to. I wanted to add some additional sizes to the images, so I used "add_image_size" and regenerated the thumbnails. But I can't get the larger sizes to show up in the coding.

```
add_image_size( 'iphone', 450 );
add_image_size( 'phone-large', 650 );
add_image_size( 'tablet', 850 );
add_image_size( 'laptop', 1400 );
add_image_size( 'laptopretina', 1600 );

function images_fox($imageID){
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $imageID, 'full' );
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $imageID, 'full');
    $alt = get_post_meta( $imageID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)

    return '<img src="' . esc_url( $img_src ) . '" srcset="' . esc_attr($img_srcset ) . '" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 450px, (max-width: 600px) 650px, (max-width: 800px) 850px, (max-width: 1024px) 1024px, (max-width:1350px) 1400px, (max-width:1550px) 1600px, 2300px" alt="' . $alt . '">';
}
```

**The laptop and laptopretina should both be showing up in the srcset, but instead I get this the following:**

```
<img src="/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner.jpg" 
srcset="/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner.jpg 1920w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-300x150.jpg 300w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-768x384.jpg 768w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-1024x512.jpg 1024w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-450x225.jpg 450w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-650x325.jpg 650w, 
/sp-content/uploads/2018/08/banner-850x425.jpg 850w" 
sizes="(max-width: 300px) 450px, (max-width: 600px) 650px, (max-width: 800px) 850px, (max-width: 1024px) 1024px, (max-width:1350px) 1400px, (max-width:1550px) 1600px, 2300px" alt="Alt Image">
```

The 1024 size is there, but then it jumps to the default size at 1920. 1920px is the full image size. I just can't seem to figure out why it's not pulling the two custom sizes. The images at those sizes exist.

I've even tried uploading the image again to see if that was the problem.

*Note: I shorted the URL for the images.*

Comment: What theme are you using? Are you using a gallery plugin? If so which plugin is it?

Comment: this is coded into a custom theme, and there is no plugin dealing with this. It's all custom coded.

Comment: Does your custom code use the filter 'max_srcset_image_width'? It sets the maximum width of images in the srcset. The default is 1600 which should have worked for you unless it was overridden.

Comment: Make sure the size is not cropping the image, changing its aspect ratio. Remember that: "image sizes matching the aspect ratio for the original image will be returned". As stated here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_calculate_image_srcset/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: I got this fixed, but I cannot remember what I did now... sorry to all future googlers.

Comment: @KimberlyFox will you share your updated code ?